# Orbeon Forms - Time Stamp to display on Form control

Tags: timestamp, orbeon

I want to know if there is a way to display the value of the current time (Time stamp) to a form control such as text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`current-dateTime()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-current-dateTime). And for proper formatting of the value, you'll most likely want to use a *Date and Time* control.